# Interchanging supremum over a function and integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

Under what conditions can the following equality hold true
$$
\sup_{f \geq 0} \int_{\mathbb{R}} a(x)f(x)dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}}  \sup_{f \geq 0} a(x) f(x)dx , $$
where $a(x)$ is a real-valued function and $f$ is the density function, i.e., it satisfies $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) = 1$ and $f \geq 0$. 
I read this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2852005/interchange-between-integral-and-sup), but the integrand is a sequence of functions. In my case, is it obvious that the equality will hold true since the sequence of functions reduces to an identical sequence? Are there any sufficient conditions on $f$ here? Any reference/help please!

Comment: Are you taking $\sup$ over all integrable functions or some given family of functions?

Comment: How does the quantities depend on $f$? It looks that LHS is just infinity, the integrand of RHS is ill-defined.

Comment: @FZan over all integrable functions.

Comment: @Ayaka Yes, I agree...I am editing my question, I removed major chunks of my problem to simplify. Apparently, in the paper, two cases are made from  the left term; a(x) >=0 and <0. One is show to be infinite and the other 0. I believe it somehow follows, provided the above equality holds. Maybe it is implicit, I am not sure, hence my question.

Comment: you need to specify over which class of function the supremum is taken

Comment: @SydAmerikaner f is the density function here. Edited the question.